# Why there is no hat for taking back downvotes?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2017

I am seeing a hat for nearly every feature, like editing 5 old questions (Werewolf Hunter), cleaning up comments after post owner edit (It's a me), removing 10 unnecessary comments from 2017 (This is Fine), Vote 7 times from app (Too cool), etc.

Should we have one for cleaning up downvotes, which should be removed when post owner edited legitimately? As the downvoter won't get notification as he didn't comment (if I am not wrong) and the owner cannot ping the downvoter to get revision?

This will motivate someone to revisit & revert their downvotes.

Comment: There will probably be a topic similar to https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289302/295232 at the end of this year's Winter Bash. It's better to propose it there.

Comment: Do we have a hat for down-voting posts?

Comment: Taking something away from others is not in the holiday spirit. Instead of greedily hoarding your downvotes this holiday season, you should share them with others and have joy in your heart.

Comment: taking away love is not good, but taking away wrath is always good.. best holiday mood ever,

Comment: @TinyGiant: You are doing it [again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360982/17-questions-all-on-the-same-topic-with-no-good-answers#comment541933_360982) ;)

Comment: @ArunVinoth if "wrath" is how you see downvotes, I greatly suggest changing your mindset :/....

Comment: @Patrice I dont have this mindset for all the downvotes.. never judge anyone..

Comment: @Arun Well I was basing myself off of what you said. Maybe... if you don't want people to think you see downvotes as "wrath".... not calling them that would be a good step :)

Comment: @Patrice opinion differs.. I assume SO is all about [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254137/enhance-moderation-ability-by-encouraging-excellent-content)

Comment: @Arun This frankly feels like we're derailing into other topics. To my points: Downvotes are NOT wrath, they are quality control mechanisms. You can decide to upvote more than you downvote, and see yourself as "encouraging", of course (a lot of other users would tell you there is a ton of content deserving moderation that doesn't get it because people don't want to downvote though, and that is a problem for Stack). That doesn't mean downvotes are bad though.

Comment: @Patrice my point is: let downvoters prove that they care about SO content more & will always change their decision of downvoting when the post improves..

Comment: Meh - someone else can handle a question if it's been improved.  I've done my bit when downvoting it when it was bad, and I'm surely not inclined to follow up on old, bad questions instead of handling new, good questions.   @ArunVinoth ' let downvoters prove that they care about SO content more' - no.  Why should I put in effort on some maybe-improved question when the OP could not be bothered originally?  A hat/badge is not gonna do it.

Comment: When a question is edited, my understanding is that it's pushed to the home page, making it visible so that more people vote on it, thus giving the OP the chance to get upvotes if they fixed their question. But the downvoter isn't responsible for the fact that the OP put a bad question to begin with, so they shouldn't be expected to trudge through all their old downvotes looking for improvements.

Comment: So, why don't you sail?

Comment: @Arun I totally agree to that, even if not everybody is of that mindset. is there any point where I seem to have said that downvotes, once the post is edited, shouldn't be changed? What I said is that seeing downvotes as "wrath" is a slippery slope. Your point isn't relevant to that. I am talking SOLELY about you saying downvotes is wrath. The conversation needs not be moved away from that.

Comment: @Patrice am coming there.. if you see my original question (see edit history), I was concerning about hurry voters & keep mine too folks.. I don't worry about lifetime downvotes on low quality posts, consider hidden gems.. bring the trust that people also do better things than SO bots..

Comment: Frankly unsure what you mean here. I think it's better to just leave this be, I frankly don't understand why you are making the points you are making. This makes the whole conversation impossible to follow (btw, no need to check edit history. It was just proofread, nothing changed in your meaning...)

Answer (score 11):

There are generally two reasons we don't have hats for a particular action:

1. We didn't think about it;
2. We can't track whatever the action is in a way that makes a hat feasible. (For example, a hat like "view 10 questions in a tag" is a non-starter.)

As far as retracting downvotes goes... it's a bit of both of those. I don't think we considered vote retraction hats at all, but it's a moot point since we don't track who deleted a given vote.